# Create a test in Playwright with fetch calls

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, e2e-testing, playwright

So i want to write a e2e test using Playwright, and this is what the website does (i'm using React):

- When it first renders, it fetches a random fact from an API, and then it uses the first three words as a query to fetch a random picture from another API. Both the fact and the picture are shown after fetching.
- There is also a button that gets a new fact with a new fetch request, thus it also gives you a different picture by using the three words from the new fact instead, so it's like reloading the page again.

The test that i want to write has to check that when the user clicks the button, the new fetches are succesful, and the new fact and image are different from the previous ones (i already have a test to check that there is an initial fact and picture).

I tried to save the first paragraph and picture in some variables, then click the button, wait for response, get the new paragraph and pictures and expect them to be different from the previous ones.

Code for the test attempt:

```
const button = await page.getByRole('button') 
const prevText = await page.getByRole('paragraph') 
const prevImage = await page.getByRole('img') 

await button.click() 
page.waitForResponse(res => res.status() === 200) 

const newText = await page.getByRole('paragraph') 
const newImage = await page.getByRole('img')
 
await expect(newText).not.toEqual(prevText) 
await expect(newImage).not.toEqual(prevImage)
```

i also tried to have the click and waitForResponse inside of a Promise.all but it didn't work either

website code: https://github.com/krst221/test2
deploy: https://test2-krst221.vercel.app/

Comment: Please share your code as a [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Please [edit] the post for the code update and show the page as well as the code so it's fully runnable and we can see what's being automated/tested.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the snippets you provided in your question, I see two main potential culprits that are likely causing you issues.

### 1 - The response is not actually getting `await`ed

The `waitForResponse` method returns a promise that needs to be `await`ed, otherwise it’s not actually being waited for by the code/test. Also, that wait and promise needs to start before you click, and `await`ed after in order to actually get to the click while also watching for the response. So you would need to change the code to be something like this:

```js
const responsePromise = page.waitForResponse(res => res.status() === 200)
await button.click()
await responsePromise
```

[The Playwright docs on waitForResponse](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-response) also give examples of this.

### 2 - Locators are lazy

In Playwright, Locators are lazy and just store how to locate the element(s) without actually doing it, until an action is taken on them like click. So your new and prev ones are actually equivalent. Plus, to check whether the new differs from the prev, you may be wanting to check their contents anyway. Either way, you’ll have to use the locators to get information to then compare, such as `locator.textContent()` for the paragraph.

Hope that helps!